# Get Active Directory URL inside WebPart in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory

is there a way to find out the current Active Directory's URL inside SharePoint webpart?

If I have the URL, I can use this constructor to create access to AD with current user's credentials:

```
new DirectoryEntry(<URL>, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure));
```

Might I find this URL propertry hidden somewhere here?

```
        SPSite sc = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);
        ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(sc);
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
        ...
```

Or is there any other dynamic way to create connection to AD using current user (which has AD read rights) without specifying any prior parameters in configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the people picker settings on the `SPWebApplication`:

[`SPWebApplication.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppeoplepickersettings.searchactivedirectorydomains.aspx)

If there are no domains specified you could use the global catalog as fallback:

```
GlobalCatalog gc = Forest.GetCurrentForest().FindGlobalCatalog();
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("GC://" + gc.Name));
```

Comment: Thnx for your reply. Does SearchActiveDirectoryDomains require administrative rights?

Comment: No, there are no end user permission associated on the configuration database. The SPWebApplication will be loaded with system account credentials. SearchActiveDirectoryDomains "is part" of the web application object.

Comment: One more question, I notice you using "GC://" as the protocol in the second case. How would it work with my need for "LDAP://" call? Does this mean that no LDAP provider is specified in current site and users are retrieved from Global Catalog?

Comment: SPWebApplication.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains  - for this approach I found 0 items in collection.
As I understand GlobalCatalog class is located in System.Directoryservices.ActiveDirectory which is some additional library that does not come with default .NET packages? Sorry, kinda new to C#

Comment: Yes if there are no specific peoplepicker settings for the current web application SharePoint uses the global catalog to access the AD.  `System.Directoryservices.ActiveDirectory` is part of the .net framework. Just add them as reference in VS.

Comment: Huh, only 3 references available: System.DirectoryServices, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and System.DirectoryServices.Protocols. Whole drive search returned 0 results. Should I try to reinstall .NET? Currently I have libraries from .net versions of 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0.

Comment: `GlobalCatalog`, `Forest` and `DirectoryEntry` are all in: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.DirectoryServices.dll`

Comment: I cannot seem to get the GlobalCatalog working inside the webpart, when I add that line of code, there will be just a "Unexcpected exception" and no error event is stored in eventvwr.msc

Comment: You can get more error details by adding a try-catch and printing the error message and stack trace on your own (test wise). What do you get?

Comment: nothing, the webpart wont even reach to that point of displaying any exceptions inside webpart. Could the problem be higher? E.G. sharepoint needs this additional .DLL to be added to its lib? The worst part is i cannot see the actual cause of failure in eventlog.